# Common env variable between c++, python and bash

Tags: python, c++, bash, environment-variables, shared-libraries

I have an application that is composed by different layers and written in three different languages: c++, bash and python
EDIT: on a Linux/Raspbian platform

Since now we are managing different build, platform depending, with different branches of sw development, but I'm trying to merge everything in a single branch to increase maintainability.

Do you know if there is a (and which is the better) method to share env settings between c++, bash and python?

The point is to distinguish if I'm building for platform A or platform B, and the only idea I have is have a different file per every language to set up. Is there a way to have a single point with the information?

Comment: Normally this would go into CMake or similar. Do you really need to know for which platform you build in C++? If you supply different include paths etc. depending on target, it would not need to be visible in any code that there are different platforms.

Comment: thanks for asnwer,
i have different code in cpp file

Comment: and the point is to have a unique point where cpp, bash and python access the info of the platform

Comment: I assume very little C++ code needs to be different between Linux and Raspbian? Have you isolated those parts? You don't have your codebase littered with `#ifdef`s I hope

Comment: actually the code is raspbian but i have different behaviour to enable accordin to the HW attached to the Rpi.. and unfortunately i have sparse code in the three languages i mentioned.

Comment: Ok, I don't have a "fixes-it-all" solution but I scribbled down my ideas. Perhaps you'll find something useful in there.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the platform the environment variable declaration will be different. For linux you might want to use:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  
int setenv(const char *envname, const char *envval, int overwrite);
```

But you would have to distinguish the platforms. Another way is to have a configuration file with a lock to share those variables but this is also platform dependant (the file lock mecanism).

A solution that is platform independent is to have some form of communication between the different programs (IPC).

Comment: the platform is linux, sorry I modify to clarify this point

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution for this mixed environment but rather an idea how to organize the C++ part of it. Perhaps the structure could be reused to make something similar for `bash` and `python` too.

I see a directory structure that could look something like below.
`src` and `include` will contain all the platform independent parts. For platform specific parts, you create a sub directory in `targets`:

```
src/
include/
targets/
   +-- linux/
   |     |
   |     +-- src/
   |         include/
   |
   +-- raspbian
         |
         +-- src/
             include/
```

In `include` you could put proxy header and an interface description for the platform specific parts.

`include/IFoo.hpp`

```
#pragma once

class IFooable {
public:
    virtual ~IFooable() = default;
    virtual void do_stuff() = 0;
};
```

`include/foo.hpp`

```
#pragma once

#include <foo_impl.hpp>
```

And in the target specific directories:

`raspbian/include/foo.impl.hpp`

```
#pragma once
#include <IFoo.hpp>

class foo : public IFooable {
    void do_stuff() override;
};
```

`linux/include/foo.impl.hpp`

```
#pragma once
#include <IFoo.hpp>

class foo : public IFooable {
    void do_stuff() override;
};
```

Both `IFooable` implementations are totally unaware of eachother but they implement the same interface - which is what you will be using in the rest of the platform agnostic code.

You then only need to make the build system decide which implementation to select. A simple `Makefile` could look like:

```
raspbian:
        $(CXX) -Iinclude -Itargets/raspbian/include ...

linux:
        $(CXX) -Iinclude -Itargets/linux/include ...
```

The key part is to identify when you need to do things differently on the different platforms. When you feel an urge to `#ifdef` ... `#else` ... `#endif` something, it should automatically make you stop and wonder if this is something trivial (like a one-liner) or if the implementations really are different beasts. If you come to the conclusion that it's non-trivial difference, think about what common interface you would like to have and define an interface class for that. Then go ahead and implement the two different solutions. In the platform agnostic part of the code, it will be clean. No trace of the difference between the linux and raspbian implementations will be seen.